# How to get React state array to permanently update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, state

I'm learning Node and React and now know how to integrate them and am working on making registration and login using Node and React. I'm going step by step, so currently I'm trying to at least get the inputs and put them into state as an array, and then after I get that I will go to hashing the password, sending the data to Node and the database, et cetera.

At the moment however, I'm a little bit stuck here. I'm trying to enter the username and password into my "details" state and then render it on the screen (or console log it, or whatever), but when I do it it shows up very quickly and then disappears. Why is the details state reverting to an empty array? How do I fix it? I did some research on here but couldn't figure it out.

```
import { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [details, setDetails] = useState([]);

  const readUsername = (e) => {
    setUsername(e.target.value);
  }

  const readPassword = (e) => {
    setPassword(e.target.value);
  }

  const updateDetails = () => {
    setDetails([username, password]);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Register</h1>
      <form>
        <label htmlFor="username" name="username">Username: </label>
        <input htmlFor="username" name="username" onChange={readUsername} />
        <br/>
        <label htmlFor="password" name="password">Password: </label>
        <input htmlFor="password" name="password" type="password" onChange={readPassword} />
        <br/>
        <button onClick={updateDetails}>Submit</button>
      </form>
      <h1>{details}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: My guess is because you're not binding the values to the inputs, for example: `<input htmlFor="username" name="username" onChange={readUsername} value={username} />`. That being said, I always recommend against maintaining redundant state and `details` is purely derived from `username` and `password`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forms in React have the default behaviour as in HTML: refreshing the page upon submission.

React state only exists during the component's life. When you refresh the page, the component is unmounted, and the state is lost.

To prevent the page refresh, use a function to handle the form submission, and prevent the default behaviour.

```
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
}

return (
  ...
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      ...
    </form>
  ...
  );
}
```

[View demo on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/prevent-form-refresh-8hd8s)

**Further reading:**

- [Forms in React](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html)
- [Preventing default behaviour of events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

Answer (score 3):

with the onChange handler on your input's, it is considered a "controlled" component. you also need to assign the `value` prop.

`<input onChange={readUsername} value={username} />`

Answer (score 1):

You want to create a controlled input so you should pass the `value={password}` attribute

like this:

```
<input htmlFor="username" name="username" onChange={readUsername} value={username} />
```

Also, I'd change how you handle to form. Change the button to `type="submit"`
like this
 `<button type="submit">Submit</button>`

And then handle the submit from the `<form>`

like this:

```
<form onSubmit={(event) => updateDetails(event)}
```

And then on the function, you can use the submit event like this for example

```
const updateDetails = (e) => {
event.preventDefault()
...rest of logic
}
```